# Equation for the line of a derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

So, I was doing some calculus application exercises and I can't get the following question:

> To attack enemy positions, a fighter jet flies at low heights, going through the trajectory determined by the graph of the following equation:
>
> $$f(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x}, x > 0$$
>
> **a** - Determine, by the derivative definition, the equation for the line tangent to $f(x)$ at a generic point $(a,f(a))$.
>
> **b** - If a shot is made at the position $(1,2)$, determine at which point it hits the $x$-axis.
>
> **c** - Determine the point on the graph of $f(x)$ at which a shot has to be made to hit a target at the point $(8,0)$.

I already got the derivative:
$$f'(a) = -\frac{1}{a^2}$$
I know that I have to use the definition
$$y - y_0 = m(x - x_0)$$
However, I cannot get past that.

Comment: You've got the slope. Now use the eqn: $y = f'(a).x + c$ and find out c, putting $x = a, y = f(a)$ for parts b and c, the values of a and f(a) are given. Use them to find c.

Comment: Why is it that x = a and y = f(a) for this solution?

Comment: the line is a tangent to $(a,f(a))$. Hence , it must be a solution of the lin

Comment: Are we to assume that the shot follows the tangent line at the point at which it’s taken?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if you use:
$$y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$$
You should obtain:
$$y-f(a)=f'(a)\cdot (x-a)$$
$$y-\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)=-\frac{1}{a^2}(x-a) \tag{1}$$
Equation $(1)$ is the general equation for the line tangent to $f(x)$ for a generic point $(a,f(a))$.

---

For **(b)**, all you need to do is substitute $a=1$ into $(1)$ since the shot is made at $x=1$. Thus, you should obtain the tangent line at the point $(1,2)$.

---

For **(c)**, you must find the value of $a$ such that the tangent line (Given by $(1)$) intersects with $(8,0)$. To do so, just substitute $x=8$ and $y=0$ into $(1)$, and find the positive value of $a$ for which this equality satisfies. That value of $a$ will be the $x$-coordinate of that point. Use $f(x)$ to find the $y$-coordinate of the point.